# Is there a special name for the prime knots that have a hyperbolic volume of 0.0?

Tags: knot-theory

Is there a special name for the prime knots that have a hyperbolic volume of 0.0? They have

For example $3_1$, $5_1$, $7_1$, $9_1$ from the [Knot Table](http://katlas.org/wiki/The_Rolfsen_Knot_Table). Also it seems there is some relationship between these knots, which are odd, and some links that are even, like [L6a3](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/L6a3).

Comment: These are exactly prime knots/links whose exteriors are graph-manifolds. I do not think there is a special name.

Comment: These knots are not hyperbolic (the ones you list are torus knots), so they don't really have hyperbolic volumes.

Comment: A knot (or link) falls into exactly one of three categories: [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot), [satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_knot), or [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_link).  Only the hyperbolic knots have a hyperbolic volume.  So by convention, we say that the hyperbolic volumes of torus and satellite knots are zero.